# Crontab scripts stops after device is opened from suspend

Tags: suspend, power-management, cron, battery

I'm using crontab for limiting the battery percentage of my asus laptop using the method provided in this link:

[How To Limit Battery Charging (Set A Charge Threshold) For ASUS Laptops On Linux](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/02/how-to-limit-battery-charging-set.html)

The method I'm using is the last one. The crontab one.

It works after restart but if i leave for a while and wake the laptop up from suspend the laptop continues charging instead of staying at 60%.

If I run the command in the terminal it will work but will also stop working when I wake the laptop up from suspend.

Ubuntu 20.10
64-bit

Comment: Pleas copy and paste the link. The first few characters are not included in the link for some reason.

Comment: I have attempted to fix your link - please check that it is correct

Comment: Sounds like the threshold, which is set at reboot, is lost following a resume. Why not switch to the systemd method? There is a good chance this is a bug.

Comment: The one with the creating a service file? ok.

Comment: I used the service method and it works but again after i wake it up from suspend it starts charging. I have to start the service from the terminal again for it to work

Comment: Does ubuntu reset the battery limit every time i open from suspend?

Comment: I checked after the suspend. The battery threshold file says 60. ITs just that the lap keeps charging. I have to run the command again. The mod of the site i provide the link in the question sent me this [link](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/06/easily-set-charging-thresholds-for-asus.html) . I'm still facing the same problem.